# Javascript: Looping a Textarea list into an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, excel, loops, textarea

I am trying to retrieve information typed into a Textarea element, load that into an array so that I can output a string. To be more specific, I have an excel sheet with a number, a name, and another number. i want to paste that list into the Textarea, populate an array and output messages custom to the array information per line. (So a message that would have the number, the name, and then another number, go to the next line and do a whole new message with the next three array indexes.)

I can create an array from the Textfield using a for loop and the split() method. Now how do I get Javascript to go to the next line and treat that as a new message and load the new indexes for my next message for as long as the length of the list?

this is my test script so far.

```
function resultFunction(){

var x = document.getElementById("statusForm");
var text = " ";
var i;

        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    text += x.elements[i].value;

        }

var loadArray = text.split(",");
var loadID = loadArray[0];
var carrierID = loadArray[1];
var poID = loadArray[2];
console.log(loadArray);
console.log(loadArray.length);




document.getElementById("resultsArea").innerHTML = "Hello " + carrierID + ", <br />Please send me status on the following loads <br />" + loadID + " <br />Thank you!";

};
```

Comment: Please post a data sample (the thing you would paste), at least two or three lines worth; and also a desired output.

Comment: I did, it is at the bottom ("resultsArea") it prints to a div below the text field. Although when I can get this working on multiple lines I will make it scrollable. Its just a test message but the final will probably be a paragraph output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to read line by line from text area and split each line into values as you want.
For e.g

```
var lines = document.getElementById("statusForm").split('\n');
 for (i = 0; i < lines .length; i++){
     var text = x.elements[i].value;
     var loadArray = text.split(",");
     var loadID = loadArray[0];
     var carrierID = loadArray[1];

     document.getElementById("resultsArea").innerHTML = "Hello " + carrierID + ", <br />Please send me status on the following loads <br />" + loadID + " <br />Thank you!";
 }
```

Similiar to the above it will work

Comment: Thank you. I really should have broken it up better, I ended up trying to make one variable do all the work. lesson learned.